# Control output of MiniProfiler for .NET in web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, miniprofiler

I followed the setup instructions here https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore and got Mini Profiler working with my ASP.NET core web app.  I pushed the code up to my staging site and now see the output on every request.

Previously local only access was documented here https://miniprofiler.com/

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
...    
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}
```

How can I restrict miniprofiler to only show for local requests in ASP.NET core

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
services.AddMiniProfiler(options =>
{
    // (Optional) To control authorization, you can use the Func<HttpRequest, bool> options:
    // (default is everyone can access profilers)
    options.ResultsAuthorize = request => CanAccessMiniProfiler(request);
    options.ResultsListAuthorize = request => CanAccessMiniProfiler(request);
}
```

You can implement it any way you like:

```
private bool CanAccessMiniProfiler(HttpRequest request)
{
    // Add your logic here, e.g. check for local requests and certain roles
}
```

Comment: I missed that. I was looking for something like the original example that had a check for Request.IsLocal (https://miniprofiler.com/). It's surprising difficult to check for if the Request is local in .net core

Comment: You could consider using `IHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` in stead of determining if the request is a local URL.